# Schedule task from script in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I want to make a script that schedules the writing of date and time in a txt file.

```
*1 * * * * date >> ultimoscript.txt
```

Now I need to know where this crontab is or how I can write the previous code using the script.

I tried with crontab -e but it is not possible

```
contrab - e *1 * * * * date >> ultimoscript.txt
```

I need to solve this because I can not use crontab directly it has to be through a script that the program crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
crontab -l > tempfile
crontab <<EOF
`cat tempfile`
* * * * * date >> ultimoscript.txt
EOF
```

The above code is useful if you would like to append a crontab entry to the current crontabs.  Here is the explanation:

crontab -l lists the current crontab entries for the current user.  Save this to a tempfile.  We're going to append a new crontab entry to tempfile.

The command is just crontab.  When crontab is invoked without parameters, it replaces all cron entries with its stdin.  In this case, we are redirecting stdin from a heredoc (the content between <

I would consider it more readable if I wrote the code this way, but I was just giving you a quick answer above:

```
crontab -l > tempfile
echo '* * * * * date >> ultimoscript.txt' >>tempfile
crontab <tempfile
```

Comment: This is a very good idea and very simple. I had not thought about it.

I have been complicating this simple problem a lot.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can edit by run command:

```
crontab -e
```

and then put in there:

```
* * * * * date >> ultimoscript.txt
```

save the crontab and restart the cron service

Comment: AFAIK, on most platforms (including Ubuntu) there is no need to restart cron service.  Typically, editing crontab as described by shushu should be sufficient.  Also be aware that with cron, the PATH used by cron service is typically different than your default PATH.  It's helpful to put the full path of the executable (although date is usually in cron's PATH ).    Also, the working directory defaults to the cron entry owner's home directory.    If you ever wonder about the environment that cron uses, you can create a cron job with just '* * * * * set > cron-env.txt' as an entry.

Comment: What I need is a script that automates what you write.

I need to write the code in the crontab using a script

Comment: correct, you don't must to restart the cron service... just good to have. and pay attention to the PATH as @Mark said, save the output to full PATH.

Comment: how do you run the script? regular bash?

Comment: Yes it is , regular bash OK guys . I'll take your advice and apply it, thank you very much guys